# Какое из двух действий происходит?

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток. Есть код, в котором вызывается метод `Object.ReferenceEquals()`. Вопрос: что происходит?

1)Так как класс `Object` публичный, то может спокойно вызываться данный статический метод.

2) Класс `Example` является производным классом от `Object`. В таком случае, идет обращение к статическому методу родителя класса.

```
using System;

public class Example
{
 public static void Main()
  {
    int int1 = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(int1, int1));
    Console.WriteLine(int1.GetType().IsValueType);
  }
}
```

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Оба утверждения верны.

Comment: "Родитель классa" здесь совершенно ни при чем.

Comment: голосую за 1-й вариант

Comment: @PetSerAl Единственный метод проверить это посмотреть на IL код в таком случае?

Comment: @Igor Можете объяснить почему?

Comment: @ВалерийМихеенко Что именно Вы хотите проверить? Тот факт, что Вы вызываете статический метод базового класса никак не отражается в IL коде. Просто, если класс является Вашим базовым классом, то вы можете вызывать `protected` методы, а есть нет, то только `public` (`internal` если вызываете из той же сборки) методы.

Comment: @ВалерийМихеенко Что объяснить? Каким боком здесь отношение родитель-наследник между `System.Object` и `Example`?

Comment: @ВалерийМихеенко А-а-а, так в этом что ли и вопрос?

Comment: @Igor Я знаю, что все объекты наследуются от Object. Было интересно понять, почему сам Object здесь ни при чем.

Comment: @PetSerAl Спасибо!

Comment: Единственное, что даёт наследование `Example` от `Object` в данном случае – это возможность писать `ReferenceEquals(int1, int1)` вместо `Object.ReferenceEquals(int1, int1)`, так как метод `ReferenceEquals` наследуется, но на генерируемый IL код это не влияет (при условии, что никто в цепочке наследования не переопределяет метод `ReferenceEquals`).

Comment: @rdorn А с каких это пор статические члены перестали наследоваться? Не вводите людей в заблуждение. Наследуются все члены за исключением конструктора экземпляра, деструктора и статического конструктора, статика тоже наследуется.

Comment: @PetSerAl строго по тексту спецификации вы правы. Только это какое-то кривое наследование, статические члены не могут быть виртуальными, не могут быть переопределены, используется неявное перекрытие. Т.е. по факту к ним просто предоставляется доступ as is. Похожая чушь с наследованием в интерфейсах, которое по факту не наследование, а агрегация. Чем больше перечитываю спеки, тем больше нахожу ляпов... а идея то была хорошая.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу бессмысленности второго утверждения:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public static bool ReferenceEquals(object objA, object objB)
  {
    return true или false;
  }
}

public class Example
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    int int1 = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(SomeClass.ReferenceEquals(int1, int1));
    Console.WriteLine(int1.GetType().IsValueType);
  }
}
```